# Slackware ./configure error

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, slackware

I'm new to slackware.

i'm trying to install freetds on my slackware 14.0 but i get this error when i run ./configure

config.log say:

gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc : fatal error: no input files
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc : fatal error: no input files
...
...
error: C compiler cannot create executables

Comment: and...........?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no particular reason you're avoiding [Slackbuilds.org](http://slackbuilds.org/repository/14.0/development/freetds/), then you'd be much better off either using [sbopkg](http://www.sbopkg.org/downloads.php) (with the command `sbopkg -i freetds`) or manually downloading the source tarball and the necessary files from slackbuilds.org and following the [instructions](http://slackbuilds.org/howto/) for using slackbuild scripts to make a package to install with `installpkg`.  If you need to specify flags to pass to the `configure` script, you can edit the `freetds.Slackbuild` script to specify them in there.

This will leave you able to much more easily manage removing the package at a later date if you choose to, or handling updates for newer versions of the code.